# Python: how can I pass parameters in def to inputs in pandas loc?

Tags: python, pandas, user-defined-functions

I want to pass the parameters in my def to inputs in pandas `loc` but I am not sure how to do so, as `loc` requires defined labels as inputs. Or is there any other way I can perform Excel INDEX MATCH equivalent in Python but not using `loc`? Many thanks!
Below please find my code:

```py
def get_correl_diff_tenor(p1, p2):
        correl = IRCorrMatrix.loc['p1', 'p2']
        return correl
```

`p1` and `p2` in `loc['p1', 'p2']` refer to the tenor pairs for calling the corresponding correlation value in the matrix below.

`IRCorrMatrix` is shown below, which is a correlation matrix defined by tenor pairs.

```
         2w    1m    3m    6m    1y    
Tenor
2w     1.00  0.73  0.64  0.57  0.44  
1m     0.73  1.00  0.78  0.67  0.50  
3m     0.64  0.78  1.00  0.85  0.66  
6m     0.57  0.67  0.85  1.00  0.81  
1y     0.44  0.50  0.66  0.81  1.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC remove `''`  from `'p1', 'p2'` for pass variables from function:

```
IRCorrMatrix.loc[p1, p2]
```

Comment: @IIUC means If I Understand Correctly. Function should be called like `out = get_correl_diff_tenor('2w','1m')` and return `0.73`